# Find all Integers n such that n! is not a multiple of n^2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all Integers $n$ such that $n!$ is not a multiple of $n^2$.

I first want to find the values of n such that $n!$ is a multiple of $n^2$.
Then $(n-1)! = kn$.
I am struck in how to find n.

Comment: What would your answer be looking at $1 \le n \le 10$? I.e. do $1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100$ divide $1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800$ when paired up?  Does this suggest a possible pattern? Can you prove the pattern?

Comment: Note:  If $p$ is prime, then $p$ does not divide $(p-1)!=p!/p$, and if $n>4$ is composite then $n$ divides $(n-1)!=n!/n$

Comment: Are you asking for *positive* integers ?

Answer (score 6):

As you pointed out, $n^2$ divides $n!$ if and only if $n$ divides $(n-1)!$. I will show that this occurs for all integers $n$ except for the prime numbers and $4$.

First, suppose that $n$ is not a prime or the square of a prime. Then there exist integers $1<a<b<n$ such that $n=ab$. Since $a$ and $b$ appear in the product for $(n-1)!$, it follows that $n$ divides $(n-1)!$ in this case.

Next, suppose that $n=p^2$ is the square of a prime. When $p=2$, we see that $4$ does not divide $3!=6$. Otherwise, $p\geq 3$ so that $p$ and $2p$ appear in the product for $(p^2-1)!$, so that $p^2$ divides $(p^2-1)!$.

Finally, suppose that $n$ is prime. Then it follows directly from the definition of primality that $n$ does not divide $(n-1)!$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is prime, then $p$ does not divide $(p-1)!$,

because if a prime number divides a product then it divides one of the factors,

and that would mean $p$ divides a number less than it, which is absurd.

[Also, by Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$, so $p$ does not divide $(p-1)!$.]

On the other hand, if $n=ab$ with $a\ne b $ and $a,b>1$,

then $n$ divides $(n-1)!$, which is a multiple of $ab$.

So if $n>4$ is composite or $n=1$, then $n^2$ divides $n!$,

but if $n$ is $4$ or prime then $n^2$ does not divide $n!$.

Comment: I should have included the case $n=p^2$ with $p>2$.

Answer (score -1):

If $n=p$ is a prime, then clearly, $p!$ not divisible by $p^2$.

Now, suppose $n$ is composite. If $n$ has one prime divisor, let $n=p^k$. Now, we inspect $n!=(p^k)!$ Clearly, $p^k\mid n!$, moreover $p^{k-1}\mid n!$ also holds. If $k>2$ then $p\mid n!$ and $p<p^{k-1}$, and thus, $n^2=p^{2k}\mid n!=(p^k)!$, as desired. If $k=2$, that is, $n=p^2$, then note that, $(p^2)!$ is divisible by $p^4: (p^2)!=p^2(p^2-1)!$, and since $p^2-1>2p$ holds for $p>2$, both $p$ and $2p$ appear in $(p^2-1)!$.

Next, suppose $n$ has at least two distinct prime divisors. Let $n=ab$ with $(a,b)=1$. Note that, $n!=n(n-1)!$, and thus, it suffices to show $ab\mid (ab-1)!$. But since $a\neq b$ and $a,b<ab-1$ this is immediate.

Comment: I am not able to follow the top of your second paragraph...why does $p^{2k}|n$ again?

Comment: $n!=n(n-1)!$, thus it suffices to prove $p^k\mid (p^k-1)!$. Now, if $k>2$, then both $p$ and $p^{k-1}$ appear in $(p^k-1)!$, right? For $k=2$, we simply have both $p$ and $2p$ arising in the factorial. Done. 

Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: Hi @Kawa thank you. Your explanation here in the comments makes sense and is correct. But this is different from what you wrote in your answer above. If you editted your answer in light of what you said here in the comments that would make it much clearer for the reader